# Audio record playback animation on Android

Tags: android, performance, animation

I wonder how they fill the "played" part of the view that represents an audio record. Here is an example from Telegram:

[image]

The initial color of the view representing an audio record is grey. The played part is filled with blue.

How would I implement such a thing? I would store two images. The first one would represent the audio record in the not-played state, and the second one would represent the same record in the played state.

The not-played state:

[image]

The played state:

[image]

Then I would create a `FrameLayout` with two `View`s and use [the clip drawable API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Clip) to gradually reveal the played part. Here is my code:

**clipped_view_animator.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="15000"
    android:propertyName="level"
    android:valueTo="10000"
    android:valueType="intType" />
```

**played_clip.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<clip xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:clipOrientation="horizontal"
    android:drawable="@drawable/played"
    android:gravity="left" />
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="ru.maksim.sample.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/play"
        android:text="Play"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/not_played" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/clippedView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/played_clip" />

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        play.setOnClickListener({ play() })
    }

    private fun play() {
        val clippedDrawable = clippedView.background as ClipDrawable
        Log.d(TAG, "level=${clippedDrawable.level}")
        val animator = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(this, R.animator.clipped_view_animator)
        animator.setTarget(clippedDrawable)
        animator.start()
    }
}
```

**Video:** 
https://youtu.be/9X8Yb9aKqmQ

My method works. However, I wonder if there are better ways to do what I do (in terms of performance, the number of lines of code, etc.). By the way, it's clear from my video that I exceed the 16 milliseconds per frame limit (Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 with Android 5.0.2). Might be worse in a real-world app.

Comment: How about implementing libraries to solve the issue? They tend to be more efficient.

Comment: @Abhi, what libraries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your codes seems to perform the function perfectly. However, sometimes libraries are more efficient than native code. You can refer these libraries to implement your feature.

1. [WaveForm](https://github.com/ongakuer/WaveForm)
2. [Yalantis Horizon Wave](https://github.com/Yalantis/Horizon)
3. [Audio-Recorder-Visualization](https://github.com/hiteshsahu/Android-Audio-Recorder-Visualization-Master)
4. [Semantive Waveform](https://github.com/Semantive/waveform-android)
5. [WaveInApp](https://github.com/Cleveroad/WaveInApp)
6. [WaveformControl](https://github.com/newventuresoftware/WaveformControl)

The library doesn't have the exact same implementation and you might have to tweak it to meet your requirements. I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38744579/show-waveform-of-audio) which helped me while I was working on a similar project. The answer uses native code to show Audio waveform. You can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46860408).