# How is it possible to show a preview of an audio file?

Tags: android

I'm creating an app that allows you to choose an audio file on the device, show a preview of graphical music track of the selected file and then send it to the firebase storage. My problem is to show the preview of the chosen file as I don't know if there is something that allows it. For example, for the images there is the imageview for the videos the videoview but for the audio files I don't know what to use. I add a photo of what I would like to do. Thanks in advance to those who will answer.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is a button what the user can click to play the audio, you can use a `MediaPlayer`, as suggested here: [how to play audio file in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7291731/how-to-play-audio-file-in-android)

If what you want is to make a visual preview of the waveform from the audio file, you can reference this answer, which involves creating a custom view and analyzing the audio file and render the resulting waveform: [Show waveform of audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38744579/show-waveform-of-audio)

Comment: I would like to show the preview of the selected audio file (for example an album image or a default image) as  for images or videos. I don't know if it's clearer now